# Create Nested Groups in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is there a way to create nested groups in WSO2 Identity Server using UI or the SCIM interface's Groups end point with LDAP User Store? I tried both but could not create. Is there any other mechanism or the nested groups not supported?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK,  there is no way to create nested group in WSO2IS,  it can only create LDAP groups and assign them to users. But if there are nested group in the LDAP already. Thenusers are retrieved from a particular group,  it would give the all users within nested group as well.. However, if you are familiar with XACML, you can use hierarchical groups using [this](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-rbac-v1-spec-cs-01-en.pdf) profile. XACML is supported by WSO2 Identity Server to achieve these goals

Comment: Hi Asela, thank you for the response. I looked at the profile you sent and it allows creating policies based on hierarchical roles but requires the system providing those roles to take care of the hierarchical roles handling and though WSO2 IS supports XACML it does not support hierarchical roles/groups CRUD operations unless some other system is used to provide that information to WSO2 IS PDP via PIP interface. What I am looking for is a CRUD operations for nested groups management via SCIM or some other interface in WSO2 IS to create nested groups.