# WSO2 APIM Roles and permissions - inheriting permissions to users via nested LDAP groups

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When configuring a user store with class `ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager`, it is possible to list AD groups in the carbon `GUI` at roles section only when the group filter implicitly searches for them. Then permissions to users that are members of those roles are inherited.

Is it possible to grant permissions to users which are members of a AD groups that are part of a group hierarchy (nested groups) by setting permissions only to the root parent AD group?

For example, the following nested groups (indentation matters for the group/member hierarchy):

```
GROUPA
    GROUPB
       User1
       GROUPC
           User2
           User3
```

This means that the group search filter will only contain the `GROUPA` and permissions would be given to the role `GROUPA` and will be inherited to `User1`, `User2` and `User3`.

I do not see this in the documentation but I want to ask if there are attributes that can be added to the user store `xml` that can help achieving this or if there is a class that you have available that supports the above scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested Groups in WSO2 Identity Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682692/nested-groups-in-wso2-identity-server)

Comment: AFAIK No nested groups are queried from an LDAP. Though I've seen a "transient" layer over an LDAP (OpenLDAP) returning even nested groups, that may work. However I am not sure you could achieve something like that with AD.

Comment: @gusto2 no this is not a duplicate. This is the question how to retrieve nested groups from an existing LDAP. The other ticket is how to create nested groups within WSO2 IS